# Ubuntu no longer recognises HDD partition as writable but Windows does?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, read-only

I dual-boot between Windows and Ubuntu, such that I have a partition on my HDD for the respective system files for each operating system and another partition for my documents.

I renamed the system partitions using the Gparted app, but now Ubuntu won't recognise the documents partition as read/write, only as read-only. Windows can still write to it though.

Any pointers as to how to sort this out?

Answer (score 2):

If the `ntfs-3g` package is missing, please install it. I have had the same issue (NTFS filesystems read-only) after upgrading to oneiric. If the filesystem is still read-only, install `ntfs-config` and run it to check if NTFS support is properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check how the drive is mounted with options like the following in fstab:

iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dirmode=0777 0 0 (not the most secure way to do this...)